# How do I add a custom property to a file using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

When you right click on a file in Windows Explorer and click properties and then click the Custom tab there is a list of properties. I want to add one of these custom properties using a VBScript file. The property's name must be Version and the value must be a version number such as 1.0.0.0. The file type is an msi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read and write custom file properties, you need to use the `DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties` COM object that is provided by the [dsofile.dll](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224351) library.

Here's sample code to accomplish your task:

```
Set oFile = CreateObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties")
oFile.Open("E:\Setup.msi")

oFile.CustomProperties.Add "Version", "1.0.0.0"
oFile.Save
oFile.Close
```

Before running this code, make sure you have registered dsofile.dll in the system:

```
regsvr32 dsofile.dll
```

More info on using the dsofile.dll in [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692828.aspx).