# Set file properties in Python

Tags: python, linux, file, polymorphism

In Filemanager (Linux and Windows) I can right click a file and see its properties. I would like to set them using Python. It seems complicated. With os.stat(file) I can retrieve standard file properties, but I can not set (custom) properties. There seems to be a solutions, for C# [Retrieve metadata column feilds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949397/retrieve-metadata-column-feilds) , and for VisualBasic [How do I add a custom property to a file using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726043/how-do-i-add-a-custom-property-to-a-file-using-vbscript/3787416#3787416) but I could not find anything for Python. Your help is much appreciated. Python is polymorphous, so I would expect :

```
 setattr(file, property_name, property_value)
```

but this does not work.

Comment: Could you provide an example of non-standard file properties that you would like to set?

Comment: Description, version, valid,etc.  I am building a Sanity_check to check if all required resources, for a specific program, are met. It is a kind of log file, but the result can be read in the program again, and differences can be compared. The volume of files may be as large as of logfiles. A data file (pickle) have to have descriptive info, so the user knows he has the correct file for a specific kind of sanity_check.

Comment: don't put the relevant info in the comments. [edit] your question instead

Comment: Do you need to access properties that you do not create yourself?

Comment: It would be useful, be not necessary.

Comment: If it is useful to access pre-existing custom properties then you need to use the specific API. I don't think it is portable between OSes, filesystems. You could use `pywin32` or `ctypes` to access Windows API

Comment: I looked at http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/ctypes.html and Linux seemed to be possible, but it is very complicated. Setting  properties for specific objects in general is easy in Python. But I am astonish that when the object is a file it gets very complicated. Is only writing the properties to a file and not automated reading, is there an easy solution?

Comment: [`CreateObject("DSOFile.OleDocumentProperties").Open("E:\Setup.msi").CustomProperties.Add "Version", "1.0.0.0"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726043/how-do-i-add-a-custom-property-to-a-file-using-vbscript/3787416#3787416) is Windows specific. If it is complicated to reproduces these calls using `ctypes` then use `pywin32`. The code should be almost the same

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49952/discussion-between-bernard-and-j-f-sebastian)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996407/2488942).

With a few modules you can change e.g. the creation time by @Claudiu's solution:

```
import pywintypes, win32file, win32con
def changeFileCreationTime(fname, newtime):
    wintime = pywintypes.Time(newtime)
    winfile = win32file.CreateFile(
        fname, win32con.GENERIC_WRITE,
        win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        None, win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
        win32con.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, None)

    win32file.SetFileTime(winfile, wintime, None, None)

    winfile.close()
```

pywin32, which includes pywintypes etc, is available from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/). I'm not sure if there is specific documentation for pywin32, but these types of modules are usually wrappers around the MS API, e.g. for VBA or C#. So it's often quite easy to find answers in the e.g. MS C# docs (based on my experience with office applications). This might help you to set any arbitrary file property.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it for all os. If only a specific os is possible then I need Linux. I see I added, by mistake, a windows tag. I just removed the windows tag.

Comment: No worries. I don't use Linux very often, but I believe it has many command line tools that might do what you want. E.g. 'touch' changes the last accessed date. You could run this from Python maybe

Comment: It has, and I tried see http://askubuntu.com/questions/435981/viewing-custum-attributes-of-a-file-within-nautilus  but without success. Most important I want to limit dependencies. Using a OLE object for just calling attr creates an undesired and unpredictable dependencies which are hard to maintain.

Answer (score -2):

Do not try to set metadata for files in Python. Because even if it would be possible, copying the file might lose the metadata, see http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#module-shutil  This mean using metadata will result to unpredictable results. Which is bad. Better something is not possible at all, then being unpredictable.

Work around :
I created an addition textfile meta.txt and archived these files using :

```
shutil.make_archive
```

Not beautiful at all. But this archive file can be copied, without the change loosing metadata. When un-archived all metadata of the file are accessible.